# Format error clearing TextBox parsed as integer

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am using Windows Form Application and am having an issue clearing a user textbox. The textbox is getting parsed as an int. I have a button near the bottom of the app that allows a user to clear different parts of the form, labels textboxes etc.

The labels clear fine but any textbox that has been parsed to int I get error on the TextChanged method.

```
xxx = textbox name
yyy = new int var used in other parts of code
```

when `xxx.Clear();` is called I get exception below:

An unhandled exception of type

> System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Here is example of code

```
private void xxx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // parse user text and convert to int
    yyy = int.Parse(xxx.Text);
}

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // close program
    this.Close();
}

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    xxx.Clear();
}
```

Comment: int.TryParse(xxx.Text, out yyy);

Answer (score 1):

put the textBoxName.Text in a variable and check if its value is null or not.

```
int xxx = textbox.Text ;
if(xxx == ""){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well when you use int32.parse you should be carefull that your string be not null and all contain numbers like

`"123456789"`

if you think you string might be null ot contain not number characters you should use:

`int32.TryParse(string String, out int iString);`

and use it like this:

```
int i = 0; // default  
string s = "somthing123somthing456blah";  
int32.TryParse(s, out i);
```

result should be: `123456` as integer

EDIT:
if you dont what TextChanged fire:

```
mytextbox.TextChanged -= myTextBox_TextChanged;
```

make you change and:

```
mytextbox.TextChanged += myTextBox_TextChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect something to do with code re-entry.  When `xxxTxtBox.Clear()` is called, the `TextChanged` method is called, meaning `int.parse` is called on an empty textbox (null or `string.empty` can't be parsed to an integer), throwing an exception.

A preferred way to fix that may be setting a flag upon re-entry, something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear(v=vs.110).aspx).

The easy way is put your `TextChanged()` logic in a `try/catch`, meaning that upon re-entry, the `int.parse()` fails but your user doesn't see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need evaluate if the textbox is empty:

```
enter private void xxx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // parse user text and convert to int if value is't Empty
     yyy = String.IsNullOrEmpty(xxx.Text) ? 0 : int.Parse(xxx.Text);
}
```

And try this:

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    xxx.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, as some others have pointed out, the problem you are experiencing is due to the fact that `xxx_TextChanged()` is being called when `xxx.Clear()` is called and the textbox content changes to an empty string.  This causes `int.Parse()` to execute against an empty string, which produces said error.

To circumvent this problem, you should change the `xxx_TextChanged()` method to something similar to as follows:

```
private void xxx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Parse user text and convert to integer, when able:
    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(xxx.Text)) ||
        (!int.TryParse(xxx.Text, out yyy)))
    {
        yyy = 0;
    }
}
```

Notice the key difference is the "`null` or empty" check against the text box contents.  There is no need to parse a null value or an empty string.  Also, instead of using `int.Parse()`, we can use the `int.TryParse()` method so that invalid numeric input (*e.g.*, "abc") does not produce an error, but instead is assigned some default value (in this case, `0`).

The rest of the code can remain as-is.